# How to resolve npm unmet dependency?

Tags: npm, sequelize.js, uuid

## Problem

My web app uses Sequelize ORM along with ExpressJS for serving the back end and Handlebars templating on the front end.

Everything used to work fine but now I'm not able to run the server app due to an unmet dependency error.

Specifically, Sequelize has a dependency on uuid@^8.1.0 that I cannot seem to resolve.

I am familiar with NPM and Node as well as the other packages I am using and cannot resolve this dependency for the life of me.

## What I Have Tried

Installing Sequelize and UUID packages globally using the command:

```
npm install -g sequelize
npm install -g uuid
```

I've also tried installing a Node package specifically made to resolve tricky npm dependency issues called 'npm-install-missing'. This also did not resolve the issue.

I've also tried 'npm upgrade' but receive an error stating that uuid is outside the uuid package which I do not understand. Here is the resulting error from running 'npm upgrade':

```
C:\Users\benar\Documents\Dev\Test\NodeExpress\testwebproject>npm upgrade
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path C:\Users\benar\Documents\Dev\Test\NodeExpress\testwebproject\node_modules\.bin\uuid
npm ERR! Refusing to delete C:\Users\benar\Documents\Dev\Test\NodeExpress\testwebproject\node_modules\.bin\uuid: is outside C:\Users\benar\Documents\Dev\Test\NodeExpress\testwebproject\node_modules\uuid and 
not a link
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\benar\Documents\Dev\Test\NodeExpress\testwebproject\node_modules\.bin\uuid
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\benar\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-08T19_18_39_086Z-debug.log

C:\Users\benar\Documents\Dev\Test\NodeExpress\testwebproject>
```

Someone left a comment with the suggestion to uninstall both sequelize and uuid then install uuid and sequelize again in that order. After doing this, I attempted to run my app again and received the following error which I'm fairly certain is the same as before:

```
C:\Users\benar\Documents\Dev\Test\NodeExpress\testwebproject\node_modules\uuid\dist\esm-browser\index.js:1
export { default as v1 } from './v1.js';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1172:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1277:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1105:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:967:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1145:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:75:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\benar\Documents\Dev\Test\NodeExpress\testwebproject\node_modules\sequelize\lib\utils.js:7:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1256:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1277:10)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

What else can I try to fix this issue?

Comment: you can first install uuid@^8.1.0 and then Sequelize

Comment: So uninstall sequelize and uuid, then try installing uuid first, THEN sequelize?

Comment: yes, please.....

Comment: Hi Raj, you must have solved my dilemma because I haven't revisited this. Just wanted to say thank you even though it's very late!